# Получить все заглавные буквы из строки

Tags: c++

У меня есть строка. Мне нужно получить список или массив из всех заглавных букв английского алфавита. И чтобы буквы в списке не повторялись.

К примеру: str = "AvB^Cv(A^B)";

Должен получить:
["A", "B", "C"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитал много всего, и в конце решил просто проверять каждый символ строки, `str[i] >= 'Z' && str[i] <= 'A'`. И если условие тру, то пушу в сэт. А у него по дефолту свойство не пушить элементы, которые уже есть в нём.

Код в Qt Creator:

`std::set<QString> letters;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if ((str[i] <= 'Z') && (str[i] >= 'A')) {
            letters.insert(QString(str[i]));
        }
    }`

Comment: O(n lg n), хотя задача - O(n)

Answer (score 5):

Раз стоит тег `c++`, `unordered_set` вам в руки! :) Хотя по мне - так проще сканировать строку и отмечать наличие букв в массиве из 26 `bool`...

Вот вариант с `bitset`:

```
string str = "csvCFCjgcgbcYcgmCUYGlhKBNJHulGCVcjgfD";
bitset<26> b;
for(auto c: str)
{
    if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) b.set(c-'A');
}
vector<char> v;
for(size_t i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
{
    if (b[i]) v.push_back('A'+i);
}
for(auto c: v)
{
    cout << c;
}
```

Или

```
unordered_set<char> u;
for(auto c: str)
{
    if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) u.insert(c);
}
for(auto c: u)
{
    cout << c;
}
```

Тоже `O(n)` в среднем.

Answer (score 1):

Решение в лоб (`c++11`):

```
std::set<char> result;
for (auto &c : str) {
    if (tolower(c) != c) {
        result.emplace(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: O(n lg n), хотя задача - O(n)

Comment: Чистый O(n) на стандартных контейнерах не сделать, или дополнительная память, или дополнительное время. Всё портит проверка на повторения.

Comment: Привел код O(n) именно на стандартных контейнерах. Да, с промежуточным `bitset`, но просто не уверен, надо посмотреть - какова сложность вставки в `unordered_set`. PS - посмотрел, в среднем вставка за O(1), так что тоже O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Используя известные нам факты, что **количество символов от `'A'` до `'Z'` меньше размера `int` (в битах)**, а также, что **числовые значения кодов этих символов в кодировке ASCII (кстати, и в Unicode тоже) идут подряд**, можно написать очень простую программу, в которой целая переменная используется как множество найденных заглавных букв.

Просматриваем заданную строку и если код очередного символа оказывается в диапазоне от `'A'` до `'Z'`, устанавливаем в 1 соответствующий бит в предварительно обнуленной переменной типа `int` (искомое множество).

Далее, просматриваем это множество и заносим находящиеся в нем буквы в массив, максимальный размер которого нам также заранее известен.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char upc['Z' - 'A' + 2], // тут будет результат
    *src = av[1] ? av[1] 
                   : (char *)"AaBbcD...XyZ."; // исходная строка по умолчанию
  unsigned int set = 0,    // временное множество, будет уничтожено при производстве результата
               i,          // индекс для перебора множества
               j;          // индекс свободного места в результате (upc[])

  for (; *src; src++)
    if (*src >= 'A' && *src <= 'Z')
      set |= (1 << (*src - 'A'));  // это заглавная буква, добавим ее в наше множество

  for (i = j = 0; set; i++, set >>= 1) // перебираем множество бит за битом, пока в нем еще что-то есть
    if (set & 1)
      upc[j++] = i + 'A'; // добавим очередную заглавную букву в результат
  upc[j] = 0;

  return puts(upc) == EOF;
}
```

Программку и gcc и g++ воспринимают как свою .

P.S.
Примерно это находится "под капотом" в программе на С++, например, из примера @Harry

**UPDATE**

Немного подумав над комментарием о том, что это печально, решил предложить вариант, сохраняющий накопленное множество и заодно оставляющий нетронутым указатель на исходные данные.

```
  unsigned int set = 0, i, j;

  for (i = j = 0; src[i]; i++)
    if (src[i] >= 'A' && src[i] <= 'Z')
      if (!(set & (1 << (src[i] - 'A')))) {
        set |= (1 << (src[i] - 'A'));  
        upc[j++] = src[i];
      }

  upc[j] = 0;
```

Конечно, теперь заглавные буква выводятся не в алфавитном порядке.

Comment: Это всё очень печально.

Comment: @alexolut, я тоже уверен, что С++ компилятор не обладает (к сожалению) такими исходными знаниями о природе данных.

Comment: о какой природе Вы говорите? Если о возможности упаковки нескольких булевых переменных в один байт, то это обеспечивается и в bitset, и в vector<bool>. Грамотно написанный C++ код имеет такую же эффективность, как C код. При этом программа пишется в более высокоуровневых абстракциях, что уменьшает шанс сделать ошибку. Конечно, чтобы утверждать об эффективности надо сравнить ассемблерный выхлоп, но я не раз уже убеждался в правоте такого подхода, и вряд ли данный случай будет исключением.

Comment: @alexolut, о том, что коды от `A` до `Z` после *небольшой трансформации* помещаются в `int`. Речь о "понимании" компилятором этой трансформации. А вот насколько (и в каких ситуациях) высокоуровневые абстракции уменьшают количество ошибок -- это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: В данном случае, мне совершенно не ясно, зачем нужен сугубо сишный подход для решения задачи по `c++`. Ваш комментарий как будто бы говорит: `С++ компилятор не обладает ... то ли дело C`. Но может быть я Вас неправильно понял. Кстати, хочу заметить, что в условиях 16-bit int, Ваш код потерпит фиаско.

Comment: @alexolut, 16-bit int? Безусловно. Там где такие int-ы еще остались потребуются соответствующие знания. А по поводу "С лучше, чем С++" -- пожалуй, Вы правы. Я не люблю кресты, считаю, что этот язык излишне сложен. Вот и показал простое (требующее минимальных знаний) необщенное (кстати, обобщить его, конечно же, можно) решение.

Comment: Для исключении ситуации с 16bit int достаточно заменить тип на `uint_least32_t`.

Comment: @alexolut, а можно сразу, для расширения кругозора, отправить читать `/usr/include/stdint.h`

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с функциональным подходом:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>

std::string s = "csvCFCjgcgbcYcgmCUYGlhKBNJHulGCVcjgfD";
std::set<char> r;
std::copy_if(begin(s), end(s), inserter(r, begin(r)), isupper);
```